# Windows 7: allow limited users to change network type

Tags: windows-7, windows, printer, network-shares, administration

I'm an intern that admins Windows machines for a school in a charter school system. When I got here everything was a mess, mainly the students had admin accounts and were turning their machines into virus infested nightmares.

So I created a clean image with an admin account for me and a limited account for students.

Because they have a limited account when they go home they can't change their network location from `Public` to `Home`. Without being able to change the network location, they can't use home network printer shares.

What I need is to be able to allow the limited account to change the network location so they can use those network printer shares (they don't need to install drivers as Windows 7 provides them).

I was hoping there was a gpedit policy I could use or a regedit solution( due to another intern at a sister school doesn't have win7 professional/enterprise ), or any other idea would be helpful.

Comment: Why can't you just modify the group policy and give the User group this permission? I won't even tell you what I [searched](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=change+network+type+windows+7+group+policy&gbv=2&oq=change+network+type+windows+7+group+policy&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0i22i30.410.7470.0.7740.44.17.1.15.15.0.700.1610.0j3j2j6-1.6.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..22.22.1760.xBA7LN2-k94) for to discover this [article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/71785-network-location-enable-disable-change.html) because it would just highlight you didn't search long enough.

Answer (score 2):

There are two Group Policy locations you'll want to check out to address this problem.

The first, most targeted option is the `Network List Manager Policies`, at `Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Network List Manager Policies`.  The `All Networks` item (or the `Unidentified Networks` item) is be the one you probably want to change, and you can change it to `User can change location`, which.. well, lets the user change the location of any network.

The second option is to basically give users control over the whole of the network connection, which you can do through the Group Policy objects at `User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Network\Network Connections` (and, of course, requires you have the requisite [Administrative Templates for Group Policy for your client OS installed](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6243)).

Answer (score 0):

As much as Ramhound needs to work on his people-skills, he is correct.  A brief search produced a link back to this page and the second search result was what Ramhound linked in his comments.  I found another link to a [Microsoft support forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/662e5ac6-b0c2-48e6-8a86-a00eaa9c4ba1/change-unidentified-network-networ-location-from-public-to-private?forum=w7itpronetworking) with a less graphical answer but the same answer.
I hope this helps.